# Problem in solving ODE with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a second order nonlinear ODE with the attached code.  After looking at the documentation for DSolve, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  When I do  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at top-level, Mathemeatica just returns the code I inputted.

[image: query]

```
DSolve[
  -x Derivative[1][y][x] - x Derivative[1][y][x]^3 + 
    y[x]* (1 + Derivative[1][y][x]^2) + 
    y[x]^2 y''[x] + (x^2 - R Sqrt[x^2 + y[x]^2]) y''[x] == 0, 
  y[x], x]
```

Comment: R is a constant.

Comment: Ok, I just posted my code (ctrl C from my notebook).

Comment: I think the mistake, if any, is to give `DSolve` an ODE that is too hard to solve.  (That's what the result indicates.)

Comment: If you multiply the `R` term by either `x` or `y[x]`, then the ODE is homogenenous, and `DSolve` can find a first integral and return an implicit solution.  I'm just pointing out it's close to an ODE that is not completely impossible, in case you made a mistake in entering the equation.

Comment: Ok, I'm fairly new to mathematica, but I would expect it to simply take a long time to evaluate, or give an error message.  Usually if I give it a computation that's difficult, the kernel takes some time to evaluate.

Comment: Interesting @Moo.  But I need R > 0 (it represents radius of earth).

Comment: Not with DSolve.  If I replace R with the number 1, it still doesn't work

Comment: With `R = 0`, it's homogeneous (see my previous comment).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: The symbolic solvers of higher order/dimensional nonlinear ODEs can use symmetry (such as homogeneity) to reduce the order of the ODE.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what the techniques are, if any. As @Moo said, you're usually stuck with numerical methods (see `ParametricNDSolve[]`).  You can also use `AsymptoticDSolveValue[]`, to get a series expansion about a point of interest, which may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: `Maple 2020.1` can compute and give me 2 solution in implicit form.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will be of help, but if you change variables to polar coordinates, we get an ODE `DSolve` can handle:

```
subs = Simplify@NestList[  (* change of variables *)
     D[First@#, x] -> Dt[Last@#]/Dt[r[t] Cos[t]] &,
     y[x] -> r[t] Sin[t], 2]~Join~
   {x -> r[t] Cos[t]};

(* new ode *)
ode = -x*Derivative[1][y][x] - x*Derivative[1][y][x]^3 + 
       y[x]*(1 + Derivative[1][y][x]^2) + 
       y[x]^2*y''[x] + (x^2 - R*Sqrt[x^2 + y[x]^2])*y''[x] /. subs // 
     Together // Numerator // Simplify[#, r[t] > 0] &;
odes = FactorList[ode][[2 ;;, 1]] == 0 // Thread
```

> ```
> (*  the process yielded a spurious factor r[t]
>   {r[t] == 0, 
>    r[t] (r[t] - R) r''[t] + (2 R - r[t]) r'[t]^2 + R r[t]^2 == 0}
> *)
> ```

```
dsol = DSolve[Last@odes, r, t]
```

> ```
> (*
> {{r -> Function[{t}, 
>     InverseFunction[-I (ArcTanh[(R - #1)/Sqrt[
>            R^2 - 2 R #1 - C[1] #1^2]] - 
>           ArcTan[(-R - C[1] #1)/(
>            Sqrt[C[1]] Sqrt[R^2 - 2 R #1 - C[1] #1^2])]/Sqrt[C[1]]) &
>      ][t + C[2]]]},
>  {r -> Function[{t}, 
>     InverseFunction[
>       I (ArcTanh[(R - #1)/Sqrt[R^2 - 2 R #1 - C[1] #1^2]] - 
>           ArcTan[(-R - C[1] #1)/(
>            Sqrt[C[1]] Sqrt[R^2 - 2 R #1 - C[1] #1^2])]/Sqrt[C[1]]) &
>      ][t + C[2]]]}}
> *)
> ```

(To connect with my symmetry comments, the change of variables shows that the system is invariant under `t -> t + t0`, which is a rotation in polar coordinates.)